# Configure IP and Port Before Build

Tags: ros2

I'm following [this](https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/core/zephyr_emulator/) tutorial to try the micro-ROS system on a Zephyr emulator. When I get to the "Configuring the firmware" step there is this line to run on the terminal:

`ros2 run micro_ros_setup configure_firmware.sh ping_pong --transport udp --ip 127.0.0.1 --port 8888`

But when I do I get this message:

> Please check firmware/zephyr_apps/microros_extensions/microros_transports.h
> for configuring IP and port before build.

The content of that header file is this:

```
// Copyright 2018 Proyectos y Sistemas de Mantenimiento SL (eProsima).
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

#ifndef _MICROROS_CLIENT_ZEPHYR_SERIAL_TRANSPORT_H_
#define _MICROROS_CLIENT_ZEPHYR_SERIAL_TRANSPORT_H_

#include <unistd.h>

#if defined(MICRO_ROS_TRANSPORT_SERIAL) || defined(MICRO_ROS_TRANSPORT_SERIALUSB)
#include <device.h>
#elif defined(MICRO_ROS_TRANSPORT_UDP)
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <poll.h>
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

typedef struct {
#if defined(MICRO_ROS_TRANSPORT_SERIAL) || defined(MICRO_ROS_TRANSPORT_SERIALUSB)
    size_t fd;
    struct device *uart_dev;
#elif defined(MICRO_ROS_TRANSPORT_UDP)

    struct pollfd poll_fd;
    char ip[16];
    char port[6];
#endif
} zephyr_transport_params_t;

#if defined(MICRO_ROS_TRANSPORT_SERIAL)

    #define MICRO_ROS_FRAMING_REQUIRED true
    // Set the UART used for communication. e.g. {.fd = 0} leads to UART_0 being used.
    static zephyr_transport_params_t default_params = {.fd = 0};
#elif defined(MICRO_ROS_TRANSPORT_UDP)
    #define MICRO_ROS_FRAMING_REQUIRED false
    static zephyr_transport_params_t default_params = {.ip = "192.168.1.100", .port = "8888"};
#elif defined(MICRO_ROS_TRANSPORT_SERIALUSB)

    #define MICRO_ROS_FRAMING_REQUIRED true
    static zephyr_transport_params_t default_params;
#endif

bool zephyr_transport_open(struct uxrCustomTransport * transport);
bool zephyr_transport_close(struct uxrCustomTransport * transport);
size_t zephyr_transport_write(struct uxrCustomTransport* transport, const uint8_t * buf, size_t len, uint8_t * err);
size_t zephyr_transport_read(struct uxrCustomTransport* transport, uint8_t* buf, size_t len, int timeout, uint8_t* err);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif //_MICROROS_CLIENT_ZEPHYR_SERIAL_TRANSPORT_H_
```

I tried replacing the `.ip` value with my ipv4 address (that one you get from running the `ipconfig` command) or the IP that one gets searching "my ip address" on Google doesn't make a difference.
If you can help me with this, many thanks!

Comment: Just adding that Google gives you a v6 IP. Make sure you are using the IP with numbers and periods, not with numbers letters, and colons.